# Sklearn custom scorer to calculate ROC AUC of top x% of predictions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I'm trying to figure out how to make a custom scorer that will calculate ROC AUC or Average Precision using only the top x% of predictions rather than all predictions.

This is my best attempt to calculate roc auc for example:

```
def top_k_roc_auc(y, y_pred):
    predictions_df = pd.DataFrame({"y": y, "y_pred": y_pred})
    k = round(len(predicitons_df) * 0.25)
    top_k_predictions = predictions_df.sort_values("y_pred", ascending=False).head(n=k)
    roc_auc = roc_auc_score(top_k_predictions["y"], top_k_predictions["y_pred"])

    return roc_auc
```

Where the expected behavior is that it would sort the predictions in descending order of probability while keeping each probably next to its associated true value and then just calculate roc auc on the top 25% of them but its just been returning the same number over and over again when I try to use it (I've tried setting 0.25 to 1 to try and replicate the results of just regular roc auc  and got different results for some reason).

Motivation for this is that in practice only the top x% of predictions will be useful so I'm more concerned how the model performs for those predictions than I am concerned with how it performs any where else.

Answer (score 0):

From your question, it's not entirely clear whether `y_pred` contains the raw scores or probability estimates, so I'll assume they are probabilities of the positive class. If they are not, you might need to adjust the following methods.

In your case, ROC AUC may not be the most suitable metric. The ROC AUC score expects a balanced distribution of positive and negative classes, which may not be the case for your top x% of predictions, especially if your positive class is rare or you are more interested in the top predictions.

A better choice may be *Precision at K*, which focuses more on the ranking of positive examples. Here's how you can implement this:

```py
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score
import numpy as np

def precision_at_k(y_true, y_test_proba):
    threshold = np.sort(y_test_proba)[::-1][int(0.25*len(y_test_proba))]
    y_pred = np.asarray([1 if i >= threshold else 0 for i in y_test_proba])
    return precision_score(y_true, y_pred)
```

Additionally, if you are interested in the number of correct predictions within the top K, you can create a custom function to achieve this:

```py
def correct_at_k(y_true, y_test_proba):
    threshold = np.sort(y_test_proba)[::-1][int(0.25 * len(y_test_proba))]
    y_pred = np.asarray([1 if i >= threshold else 0 for i in y_test_proba])
    return sum((y_pred == 1) & (y_true == 1)) / len(y_pred[y_pred == 1])
```

Use the scorers like this:

```py
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score, make_scorer

my_scorer1 = make_scorer(precision_at_k, needs_proba=True)
my_scorer2 = make_scorer(correct_at_k, needs_proba=True)
```

(I successfully tested the code with the iris dataset)